# XNA Accelerate Object every 10 seconds

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I am trying to figure out a way to make an object increase in speed every 10 seconds. The increase is nominal, something like 0.1. I am working with `gameTime.Seconds`and `gameTime.TotalSeconds` to figure out a solution but haven't nailed one yet.

My game is based on WP7/WP8

Does anyone know how I can do this?

**EDIT:**

I've just tried this:

`if (gameTime.TotalSeconds % 30 == 0)
{
Speed += SpeedAcceleration;
}`

But it falls in the if ALL the time.

Comment: It is always failing because the odds of totalseconds ever exactly being 30 is extremely remote.

Comment: There seem to be those who will downvote a question because it asks somthing they have known for a long time or is very basic. They forget they were beginners once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this should work

```
int timeSnapshot = 0;
if(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds - timeSnapshot >= 10){
Speed += SpeedAcceleration;
timeSnapshot = gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;}
```

Comment: Hmmm ok. Can you please tell me why you're doing TotalSeconds - timeSnapshot.

Comment: because timeSnapshot will be equal to the last time you decelerated. So if the current gameTime.TotalSeconds subtracted from the last time you decelerated is greater than or equal to 10, then 10 seconds will have passed so you want to decelerate again.

Comment: Ahhhhh yes yes. Now I see! Yep! Perfect. Thanks a lot that worked wonderfully. Thank you very much sabre.